# V8 constructor (group) entries such as (array), (string) grows in memory with time. How to arrest the memory growth of these entries? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-management, google-chrome-devtools, v8

I run a simple CRUD process using puppeteer for my website. I can see the heap memory growing gradually with time and the chrome's internal objects such as (system), (array), (string), (compiled code) etc. also grow in memory with time. For a 301 MB heap snapshot, approx. 148 MB is allocated for (array) and 59 MB for (system). Is there any possible way, I could arrest this from growing or is this chrome default behaviour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see unbounded memory growth (i.e. more and more usage until the tab eventually crashes with out-of-memory), then you most likely have a memory leak in your code. You can use DevTools to investigate it; if you need help, there is e.g. a detailed article at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/.

If you see a "sawtooth" pattern (i.e. memory usage slowly grows for a while (usually seconds or minutes), then suddenly drops, then slowly grows again, etc), then you're probably just seeing the garbage collector in action. Finding and freeing unused memory takes time, so V8 tries to cleverly balance how much of that it does. When there is lots of free memory available, V8 (within certain bounds) prioritizes executing your code over collecting garbage. When memory gets scarce or when there is idle time, it will spend more time cleaning up.

Comment: As mentioned by the link you provided, I have followed the methods to overcome the detached DOM leaks and have arrested the detached DOM leaks. Still memory grows over time. What could be the possible reason ?

Comment: There could be another memory leak?

Comment: My detached DOM count is zero now. Could you please what are the other possible things that may lead to memory leak or memory growth.?

Comment: Any time an object unintentionally holds a reference to another object. Custom caching schemes are a common source of such bugs; but the possibilities are endless, so I can't give you a concise list. The document I linked, in addition to leaks related to detached DOM nodes, has two more chapters (above and below) explaining how to find other leaks.